# Problem with CDN

Tags: magento-1.9, image, cdn

I'm using KeliWeb CDN and I've experienced a problem.

After having set Magento like in these pictures (https://www.keliweb.it/images/new013/cdn/guide/magento/magento2_thumb.png and https://www.keliweb.it/images/new013/cdn/guide/magento/magento3_thumb.png)

I noticed that all the images in the site appears to be down.

The src url was like `http://cdn.domain.com/media/path/to/image.jpg`, so was correct.
The backend starts to be not clickable, so via phpMyAdmin i restore default configuration, stripping out all CDN modification just done and all worked.

How to make the CDN work in Magento? I've set CDN and done the same procedure with few Magentos and all worked fine.
Am I missing something?
My reference is: https://www.keliweb.com/cdn/come-ottimizzare-magento.php

Comment: Are you hosting your store in a different geographic region to that of your customers? CDNs aren't the be all and end all of performance, more often than not all they do is increase expense, add unreliability, increase page load time and add complexity. Here's some reading https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/2gzkag/how_do_you_make_magento_lightning_fast/ckpogiw

Comment: My Magento CDN is hosted in Italy, so in the same place where customers and developers access the site. I must use CDN as our agency policy says. It is the only site that has problems with CDN (same provider, same settings, same magento)

Comment: Is your store itself also hosted in Italy? If so, a CDN is redundant and not advised.

Comment: Yes, the store is in Italy but this is not the problem. Other three magentos are italian, hosted in Italy, with same italian CDN, and they actually work. The problem is that once I've set the CDN for this Magento, it started not working properly and the backend became not clickable

Comment: Sure, I understand the issue. I'm just trying to give you a bit of insight to achieve peak performance. A lot of people are blindly recommended to use a CDN - when more often than not, they will damage performance, not improve it.

Comment: I believe you and say thank you for sharing knowledge, I noticed different changes (in better and worse) after adding a CDN. I hope I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the DNS.
At that time the DNS record for the CDN (`cdn.site.it`) wasn't already ready.